# Bash syntax error when "else" follows an empty "then" clause

Tags: shell, shell-script

Why would following script not execute, but give a syntax error of `else`:

```
LOGS3_DIR=~/logs
if [ -d "$LOGS3_DIR" ]; then
 cd
 cd "$LOGS3_DIR"
 echo "$LOGS3_DIR"
 for filename in `find "." -mtime 1 -type f`
  do
  if lsof "$filename" > /dev/null
  then
    # file is open
  else
    echo "deleting $filename"
    rm "$filename"
  fi
 done
fi
```

Answer (score 24, accepted):

[Don't use command substitution on the output of `find`](/q/321697). Here, everything can be done with `find`:

```
find . -mtime 1 -type f ! -exec lsof -t {} \; -exec rm -f {} \; > /dev/null
```

With a few `find` implementations (including FreeBSD `find` where it comes from and GNU `find`), you can use `-delete` instead of `-exec rm...`.

The reason you're getting an error is that there's no command between `then` and `else` and some shells (starting with the Bourne shell where that syntax comes from) require at least one (and a comment is not a command). Note that it is completely arbitrary and there is no reason why those shells would do that. `yash` and `zsh` don't have that limitation (`if false; then else echo x; fi` and even `if false; then else fi` work fine with them).

As others have said, you can use a noop command like `:` (or `for nothing in; do nothing; done`) or reverse the logic with the `!` keyword (available in POSIX shells, but not the Bourne shell (you'll find that using `:` for that was common in that shell)). `mksh` and `yash` happen to support `if false; then () else echo x; fi` (I wouldn't rely on it as that could change in future versions though).

Another approach is with:

```
lsof... || {
  cmd1
  cmd2
}
```

though one difference is the overall exit status which will be that of `lsof` if `lsof` fails.

Comment: While this is a much better way to do what @Novice User is attempting, it doesn't answer the question at all.

Comment: While `-exec` is often useful, as is `xargs`, sometimes a shell loop is needed. In which case a `while read name` loop is the preferred option (in bash with GNU find you can use the -0 option for both; portably you have to give up on newline).

Comment: @JanHudec, There are ways portably. `-print0` is `-exec printf '%s\0' {} +` (but portably you can't deal with that output except if you want to consider `perl`), and with `find .//.` and some post-processing, you can escape the newlines for `xargs`. Note  that it's not a `while read`, it's `while IFS= read -r`.

Comment: @Chris, I've added an answer to the  actual question since the answer ended-up being accepted.

Answer (score 133):

It seems that you want to do a *no-op* if the file is open so you should add a `:`, which is a null command in `bash`:

```
if lsof "$filename" > /dev/null; then
  # file is open
  :
else
  printf 'deleting %s\n' "$filename"
  rm -- "$filename"
fi
```

If you don't use `:`, `bash` can not parse you code, and will show error like `bash: syntax error near unexpected token 'else'`.

Comment: never new of `:` and it's the first command listed in bash-builtins.

Answer (score 27):

Another alternative: reverse your logic.

```
if ! lsof "$filename" >/dev/null;then
    echo "deleting $filename"
    rm "$filename"
fi
```

Answer (score 23):

### TL;DR

None of the other answers actually addresses your original question of why the command gives a syntax error. This is caused by a missing command between *then* and *else*.

### A Missing Command

Your original code looks like this:

```
if lsof "$filename" > /dev/null
then
  # file is open
else
  echo "deleting $filename"
  rm "$filename"
fi
```

The problem is that you have a comment between *then* and *else*, but the comment isn't treated as a command. In short, you could rewrite the problem you have (structurally speaking) as follows:

```
$ if true; then else echo; fi
bash: syntax error near unexpected token `else'
```

### Fix Your Syntax with a Bourne Builtin

You can fix this problem by placing actual commands before *else*, but a comment by itself won't do. The *if-then* section can't be empty; if you want a placeholder, you can use the [colon builtin](http://www.gnu.org/software/bash/manual/bashref.html#Bourne-Shell-Builtins). For example:

```
$ if true; then :; else echo; fi
```

Simply placing `:` into the section between *then* and *else* will fix the syntax error you are experiencing.

Comment: Gnouc answer, which is also the most upvoted one, is already adressing the original question.

Comment: Only answer to address the syntax error.

FWIW, you can reproduce a similar error with a sole semi-colon at the beginning of a line.

This will give a strong hint.

    `$ ;
    -bash: syntax error near unexpected token ';'
    `

Comment: Upvoting for the link to the Bash manual!