# why doesn’t my if structure work?

Tags: shell-script

I want to add .java to my string if it doesn't have it already.  How can I make this work with an `if` structure? This is what I tried:

```
  6 echo geef eens je naam van je java programma?
  7 
  8 read naam
  9 firstletter=${naam:0:1}
 10 
 11 naamm="${naam^}"
 12 echo $naamm
 13 
 14 add=".java"
 15 
 16 if [ ${naamm:(-5)} != ".java" ]
 17 then
 18         naamm=$naamm$add
 19         echo $naamm
 20 else
 21         #nothing
 22 fi
```

Comment: Could you take a peek at the [editing help](https://unix.stackexchange.com/editing-help), especially the first part about code blocks, and reformat the text with those? (hint, select the text and hit Ctrl-K). I don't really think the line numbers are necessary, but you could do well to add the error message(s) you get, if any.

Comment: A `then` or an `else` clause **can't** be empty or contain only a comment (you'll get an error like `syntax error near unexpected token 'fi'`).  If you really need an empty clause with only a comment, use the null/no-op statement `:`.   e.g. `if foo then; bar ; else : ; fi`  (note there must be a newline between the `else` and the `:` so this won't work as a one-liner).   See https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/133976/7696

Comment: @florian, which shell are you using? bash?

Comment: @glennjackman i am using bash and openjdk-8-jdk but i dont know what i need this openjdk-8-jdk for

Comment: @glennjackman I have one more question after that if u dont mind, now I want to write something in that file I just made "public class $naamm {" and "public main..." but i cant seem to find how to do this.. do u maybe now how to do this? thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Several possibilities:

```
if ! [[ $naamm =~ \.java$ ]]
```

or

```
name="${name%.java}.java"
```

or

```
if [ "${name: -5}" = '.java' ]
```

**additional question**

Content can be written to a file like this:

```
echo "public class $naamm {
public main..." >file
```

For bigger contents this approach is easiert:

```
cat <<\EOT >file
public class $naamm {
    public main...
EOT
```

Comment: or, `[[ $naam != *.java ]]` -- requires bash or ksh

Comment: this last one worked for me thanks a lot, does sombody now know how I could make a file with the name I readed if the file doesnt exists already?

Comment: @HaukeLaging oh i am sorry, and thanks btw, but this line gave me the error "touch: binary operator expected"

Comment: @floriandewulf Sorry, typo: `test -f "$name" || touch "$name"`

Comment: @HaukeLaging cool that worked but can i also put that in an if structure so I can give an error if the name already exists?

Comment: @HaukeLaging I have one more question after that if u dont mind, now I want to write something in that file I just made "public class $naamm {" and "public main..." but i cant seem to find how to do this.. do u maybe now how to do this? thanks

Comment: @floriandewulf See my edit.

Answer (score 1):

You can use `grep` to test if string has pattern and then append it or pass.

```
#!/bin/bash
vars=(String.obj String.java)

for v in "${vars[@]}"; do
    if ! echo "${v}" | grep -q "\.java$"; then
        appended="${v}.java"
        echo "${appended}"
    fi
done
```

Comment: Put a bang `!` in front of the command (`if ! echo ...`) and throw out the `:` and `else` lines.

Comment: or use `if grep -qv "\.java$" <<< "$v" ; then ...`